# Как проверить есть ли роль у пользователя?

Tags: python, mongodb, discord, discord.py

Надо проверить есть ли роль у пользователя.

Выводит только `kul`, а `gdf` нет

```
if collection.count_documents({"_id": member.id}) == 0:
    collection.insert_one(post)
else:
    collection.find_one({"_id": member.id})
    j = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=842092409554599936)
    print('kul')
    if get(member.roles, name='MUTE'):
        print ('gdf')
        collection.update_one({"_id": member_id}, {"$set": {"mute": 1}})
```

Answer (score 1):

Получаете объект роли на сервере и проверяете, есть ли у пользователя нужная роль.

```
role = ctx.guild.get_role(id = "123")
if role in member.roles:
    # Если роль есть
else:
    # Если роли нет
```